# Testing a Flask API when query fails

Tags: database, flask, flask-restful

I am writing a Flask application and I am using Postman to test that my endpoints are correctly written. I realized after testing everything that the only test that I could not perform was the one when the database queries failed (so that I should raise a 500 HTTP status code).

So my question is : how do I test that a query fails properly if some external service (such as a database) fails? Ideally I could test it directly within Postman but I don't know I would mock the failing service.

Comment: Use try/exept for executing or catching fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try`/`except` blocks for exceptions, below is the sample code:

```py
@app.route('/url')
def func():
    try:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(sqlQuery)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
    except:
        return "Failure"
    return "Success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Note: remember that the code is just a smaple code, where I have used `MySQL` connection and returning a normal response status.

Comment: It's better to move return 'success' to the end of try block. Agree?

Comment: Considering the programming practice, `return` in `try` block should be avoided.

Comment: Sometimes there are some errors on returning too. It's not just returning an string, it can be even more complicated... so we don't want our service breaks because of it. I prefer to include return inside try block!